# using expect to ssh 1 host, apply some commands, exit the device and ssh another device to apply some other commands

Tags: ssh, expect

Hi I'm trying to use expect for network troubleshooting between two devices.
in summary, What I'm trying to achieve is to run a script using expect which enters 2 devices and apply commands.

1. the script asks user to enter the 2 hostnames
2. Variables user,password and prompt are set
3. spawn process to ssh into the first device
4. show commands for troubleshooting purposes

All the above works fine....the problem comes when trying to ssh the other hostname, basically my script timeouts after 10 seconds and never ssh the other device.

Thanks in advance to this community for your great work helping

here is the code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

exec tput clear >@ stdout
set timeout 10

puts "Enter hostname to connect"
set c [gets stdin]

puts "which is the destination hostname?"
set dhostname [gets stdin]

#setting password variable, reading it from file
set pa [open "pass.txt" r]
set pass [read $pa]
close $pa

#setting user variable
set user xxxx

#setting prompt variable
set prompt "(%|#|\\$|>|~|:) $"

spawn -noecho ssh $user@$c;

expect {
"Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)" {send {yes};
send "\r"
exp_continue}

"assword:" {
        send "$pass\r"
        expect -re $prompt

}
}
##commands to execute on the device
send "show system uptime\r";

expect "$prompt"

send "exit\r";

expect -re $prompt

send "ssh $user@$dhostname";
```

Comment: You have `expect "$prompt"` instead of `expect -re $prompt`

Comment: Thanks for your information Jakuje. I managed to exit the first ssh session and established the other with spawn ssh "$user@$dhostname"; thnks XD

Comment: I'm unclear: do you need to connect to the 2nd machine from the 1st machine or from your computer?

Comment: You should `set pass [read -nonewline $pa]` so the password does not end with a newline.

Comment: If that's your entire script, add the line `interact` at the end -- I assume you actually want to do stuff on the "dhostname".

Comment: thanks everyone for helping, I had to exit from the first machine and then spawn another ssh to connect to the other machine

Comment: any ideas how to spawn another ssh in a new terminal window? I'm working with Solaris and $TERM is vt100